# asp.net mvc localdb initialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

How can I initialize a databse? // ASP.NET MVC 3 with msSQL(LocalDb)/V11
I want to code to upload data to the database.
ASP.NET MVC3 EF Code First

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=CompanyContext-20130203175316; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CompanyContext-20130203175316.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

**Initalize**
Descriptions of doing this.

```
namespace tesztfeladat.Models
{
    public class CompanyInitalizer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CompanyContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(CompanyContext context)
        {
            var contacts = new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact {
                    Vezetéknév="Nagy",
                    Keresztnév="János",
                    Beosztás="alkalmazott",
                    Email="nagy.janos@default1.com",
                    Telefonszám="06361254452"
                },

                new Contact {
                    Vezetéknév="Kiss",
                    Keresztnév="Ferenc",
                    Beosztás="alkalmazott",
                    Email="kiss.ferenc@default1.com",
                    Telefonszám="06361254452"
                }
            };

            contacts.ForEach(d => context.Contacts.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var events = new List<Event>
            {
                new Event {
                    Időpont=DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010"), 
                    Típusa="Tárgyalás",
                    Leírás="Éves költségvetés"
                },

                new Event {
                    Időpont=DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010"), 
                    Típusa="Tárgyalás",
                    Leírás="Éves költségvetés"
                }
            };

            events.ForEach(d => context.Events.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer {
                    Cégnév ="Default1.Kft",
                    Irányítószám= 1012,
                    Város="Budapest",
                    Cím="Tavasz utca 54.",
                    Weblap="http://www.default1.com",
                    Telefonszám="06361254452",
                    Contacts= contacts,
                    Events=events
                },

                new Customer {
                    Cégnév ="Default2.Kft",
                    Irányítószám= 2440,
                    Város="Százhalombatta",
                    Cím="Tél utca 34.",
                    Weblap="http://www.default1.com",
                    Telefonszám="063623254452",
                    Contacts=contacts,
                    Events=events
                }
            };
            customers.ForEach(d => context.Customers.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this,but dont work. :(
Help me pls! 
Thank You!

Comment: please read this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467.aspx on creating an MVC EF Code-First App. You're best off exhausting your own research before posting a question. User's here don't like to feel they are doing your work

Comment: This presentation does not contain any database initialization.

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/

Answer (score 0):

The database won't initialize until you attempt to access something from the DataContext.  Try putting this at the end of the Application_Start method:

```
using(var context = new CompanyContext())
{
    var temp = context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I modified Application_Start method:
 Database.SetInitializer<CompanyContext>(new CompanyInitalizer());

This good, but now i got new problem...

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Here:
customers.ForEach(d => context.Customers.Add(d));
Why?